# Problem with stream.distinct to check if a list have duplicates values

Tags: java, spring, list, java-stream, distinct

I have a problem with my service. This service contains an add method, which receives a form as parameter.

```
public Cheminement add(final CheminementForm cheminementForm) throws BadRequestException {
        if(cheminementForm == null){
            log.error("Cheminement can not be null");
            throw new BadRequestException("CheminementForm  can not be null");
        }else if (Objects.isNull(cheminementForm.getName())){
            log.error("All fields must be filled.");
            throw new BadRequestException("All fields must be filled.");
        }
        Cheminement cheminement = Cheminement.builder().disable(false).name(cheminementForm.getName()).build();
        List<CheminementEtape> cheminementEtapeList = new ArrayList<>();

        if(cheminementForm.getPositionsPoste().stream().distinct().count() != cheminementForm.getPositionsPoste().size()){
            throw new BadRequestException("Cannot have same positions");
        }
        for(int i=0; i<cheminementForm.getEtapes().size(); i++){
            if(cheminementForm.getPositionsPoste().get(i) < 0 ){
                throw new BadRequestException("position cannot be null");
            }
            cheminementEtapeList.add(CheminementEtape.builder().cheminement(cheminement).etape(cheminementForm.getEtapes().get(i)).positionPoste(cheminementForm.getPositionsPoste().get(i)).disable(false).build());
        }
        cheminementRepository.save(cheminement);
        cheminementEtapeService.add(cheminementEtapeList);

        return cheminement;
    }
```

This form, above:

```
@Data
public class CheminementForm {
    @NotNull(message = "{cheminement.form.name.notEmpty}")
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String name;

    @NotNull(message = "{cheminementEtape.form.etape.notEmpty}")
    private List<Etape> etapes;


    @NotNull(message = "{cheminementEtape.form.positionPoste.notEmpty}")
    private List<Integer> positionsPoste;
}
```

contains an integer list and a path list. I have a view, which contains an html form with and which returns a POST method to a controller which calls this service.

So here, in this service, the add method takes the form and adds it (via the repository). So far, everything was working.

However, I wanted to add a condition: check that the position list does not contain the same values. I added the condition, but unfortunately, it always returns the BadRequestException even when there are no duplicate values. I don't understand.

To check if there are duplicates, I used stream.distinct.count, and it should be equal to my list.

Comment: First of all, what is the input which does not work? And secondly how about `new HashSet<>(cheminementForm.getPositionsPoste()).size()  != cheminementForm.getPositionsPoste().size()`

Comment: in fact, it is a controller that calls the service. This service receives in parameters (input) a form (that I put). So, I want, before adding the object, to check that the list of the form does not contain duplicate values...

Except that when I test this and I put non-duplicated values, I still get the error: baq request exception that I created @ValerijDobler

Comment: A set guaranties no duplicated considering the hashcode & equals methods.

Comment: @ValerijDobler, I don't understand why I've this error ..

Comment: Again: what is the input which results in the erroneous output? do you send multiple leading or trailing zeros?

Comment: @ValerijDobler , the input is the List of integer positionsPoste. When I try to test duplicate values, I send a list of : 1, 2, 1, 3; and when I try to test non duplicated values: 1, 2, 3, 4 ; but the output is always the same: my BadRequestException

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
My list contained null values when I didn't check them in my view.
So before the condition, I had to remove all the null values from the list.